# request timeout while processing data from excel file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an excel sheet with data and I am processing it after reading the data. ***The problem is that, even though the processing is not done it, the request gets timed out in postman.***

```
 xlsxj({
          input: filepath,//path of the file
          output: null, // I am not taking any output of the file
          sheet: "Party Master"
        }, async function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            try {
                for(let row of result) { // more than 1000 iterations
                await fun1(row);
                await fun2(row);
                await fun3(row);
                }
                return res.send('all done');
             }
              catch(err){
                   console.log(err);
                  }

         }
    })
```

where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're API timeout because file processing is taking time.
If you are using **express** framework the default API timeout is **2 min**
what you can do is increase the timeout of the API.

If you are using express then you can simply do

```js
req.setTimeout(500000); // time in ms
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have found a solution. Return the response in finally block.

xlsxj({
          input: filepath,//path of the file
          output: null, // I am not taking any output of the file
          sheet: "Party Master"
        }, async function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          } else {
            try {
                for(let row of result) { // more than 1000 iterations
                await fun1(row);
                await fun2(row);
                await fun3(row);
                }
                return res.send('all done');
             }
              catch(err){
                   console.log(err);
                  }
finally{
return res.send('all done')
}

         }
    })
```